# What path should be used to locate CSV File used in SQL statement (Load data local infile) When WAR file Deployed on Tomcat

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, war, flyway

I have been working on Spring Boot project, I am using Flyway for database version control in this project. In migration folder there are some SQL files having "Load data local infile" Statements - referencing some CSV files.

Example:

```
load data local infile 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.5/webapps/originator/WEB-INF/classes/insertData/subject.csv' INTO TABLE subject
```

How can I make this path relative?
I have tried

```
'./classes/insertData/subject.csv'

'./insertData/subject.csv'
```

And some other combinations also but could not fixed this issue

Error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open file '../../insertData/subject.csv'for 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' command.Due to underlying IOException:
>
> BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION   java.io.FileNotFoundException MESSAGE:
> ....\insertData\subject.csv (The system cannot find the path
> specified) STACKTRACE: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> ....\insertData\subject.csv (The system cannot find the path
> specified)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to insert data into tables from CSV files within a flyway migration from a resource path. Within the migration script I used the entire path written as shown below.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE './src/main/resources/<FOLDER>/<FILE>.csv' INTO TABLE <TABLE_NAME>
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    optionally enclosed by '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

The other statements would be dependent on your file structure I just wanted to include the entire example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing SQL script you can use Java-based migration to read and insert data into a table. You can use "flyway.locations" property to specify the path for java based migration in your application.properties. As flyway by default search for "./db/migration" of resources. 
For further details check the https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#java-based-migrations